# Cache Cassandra table in scala application

Tags: scala, concurrency, cassandra

I need to get some data from Cassandra for entries in a Kafka-Streams streaming application. I'd need to perform the join on ID. I'd like to set up a cache to save time used for queries. 
The table is simple:

`id | name
---|-----
1  |Mike`

My plan is straightforward: query the table from database then store into a `Map[Int, String]`.
The main problem is - data may change in the table and needs to be updated periodically, so I need to query it from time to time.

So far I've come up with a threaded solution like this:

```
    // local database mirror
    class Mirror(user: String, password: String) extends Runnable {

      var database: Map[Int, String] =  Map[Int, String]() withDefaultValue "undefined"

      def run(): Unit = {
        update()
      }


      // 
      def update(): Unit = {
        println("update")
        database.synchronized {
          println("sync-update")        
          // val c = Driver.getConnection(...)
          // database = c.execute(select id, name from table). ...
          database += (1 -> "one")
          Thread.sleep(100)
          // c.close()
        }
      }

      def get(k: Int): Option[String] = {
        println("get")
        database.synchronized {
          println("sync-get")
          if (! (database contains k)) {
            update()
            database.get(k)
          } else {
            database.get(k)
          }
        }      
      }
    }
```

Main looks like this:

```
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

      val db = new Mirror("u", "p")
      val ex = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)
      val f = ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(db, 100, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)       

      while(true) { // simulate stream
        val res = db.get(1)
        println(res)
        Thread.sleep(10000)
      }       
    }
```

It seems to function fine. But are there any pitfalls in my code? Especially I'm not confident about thread safety of `update` & `get` functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to using Akka I would look at Akka Streams; specifically [Alpakka](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/cassandra.html) to do this. There's no need to reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

That being said the code has the following problems:

1. Existence check on cache will not help if the entries in Cassandra are updated. It will only help if they are missing from your cache
2. Look at using a [reentrant read write lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) if you believe that most of the time your cache will have the *current* entries. This will help with contention if you have multiple threads calling your mirror.

Again, I would highly recommend you look at Akka Streams with Alpakka because you can do what you want with that tool wihtout having to write a bunch of code yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Right now  restrained to use pure Kafka solution.
Existence check is intended to work that way. It will force update the thing from Cassandra if missing id comes from stream.